# IOS 8 Storyboards using SplitViewController with iPhone gets Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <MasterViewController>

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uisplitviewcontroller

I ran into an issue where I was getting "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions" errors.  This is documented in a few other SO questions as occurring for various reasons that cause a transition to start before another transition has finished, but my case does not seem to fit any of the cases that where documented.  In order to narrow down the problem, I built a small test case by doing the following:

1. Create new project using the Master-Detail Application template
2. In the storyboard, change the master table view Content setting to use Static Cells instead of Dynamic Prototypes.
3. In MasterViewController.m, comment out the table source methods.
4. Create a new file as a sub-class of UISplitViewController
5. In the SplitView subclass file, add empty ViewWillAppear and ViewDidAppear methods.

Test in the iPhone simulator and you will get the "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for " error.  Test using the iPad simulator and it does not get the error.

Any ideas on why this would happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I was entering the question into SO, the answer occurred to me.  If you add the ViewWillAppear and ViewDidAppear methods, make sure to add [super viewWillAppear:animated] and [super viewDidAppear:animated].  That resolved the "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions" errors.